# Can I have an easy comprehension?

Tags: grammar, semantics

I want to know if it is possible to say this: "He has an easy comprehension of theory and methodologies, and a complete understanding of technologies, learning very quick the use of different Business Intelligence tools."

or maybe I should change it to something like this: "He understands easily..."

I tried to find a similar sentence on Internet, but I couldn't find one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What would make you think that this is *not* grammatically or perhaps semantically correct? Just that you haven't seen it before?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `He has an easy comprehension` is the wrong way to say `it's easy for him to comprehend`. If you have a comprehension, it means you comprehend something. It has nothing to do with your _ability_ to comprehend.

Comment: @MattGutting Yes, that's the reason. I searched it in Google, but I couldn't find a similar sentence. I'm a Spanish speaker, and sometimes for me it sounds very good, but maybe it´s because my Spanish.

Comment: My suggestion is to put that fact "I searched ... but I couldn't find a similar sentence" in your question, so that people can see what your research was. Is there an equivalent correct-sounding phrase in Spanish?

Comment: "If there is some variation in that level, then one should write for the lower portion of the comprehension range, thus assuring **easy comprehension** by everyone within the comprehension range" https://books.google.com/books?id=RQwU0VGYUA8C&pg=PA29&dq=%22easy+comprehension%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ct_UVJrHBIa4uATeuwE&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBw

Comment: "... slow, effortful recognition of words through sounding out and blending did not permit easy comprehension of words" https://books.google.com/books?id=8upgA5V4v3MC&pg=PA33&dq=%22easy+comprehension%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ct_UVJrHBIa4uATeuwE&ved=0CEgQ6AEwCA

Comment: @slicedtoad you understood what I wanted to say. Thanks!

Comment: "The series of how-to videos is structured for **easy comprehension** and provides a valuable tool for individuals with diverse levels of technical ..." http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=newssearch&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQqQIoADAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.securityinfowatch.com%2Fpress_release%2F12039605%2Fsamsung-launches-new-online-training-programs&ei=J-DUVJueMIGTuATZyIEw&usg=AFQjCNGDYMjbklegxaMdtJD2HEmndfItgA&sig2=4oo4UKNliEwd_EVnhIw3IQ&bvm=bv.85464276,d.c2E

Comment: @Kris But `have an easy comprehension` is different from those examples, no? It might technically be grammatically correct, but I don't think it means what he wants it to. And it sounds off to my ears.

Comment: @slicedtoad There are two meanings. "**the action** or **capability** of understanding something." (ODO) You seem to focus on only the capability, not the action. In the OP's context, it is the action.

Comment: @MattGutting yes, if you translate the sentence to Spanish, it sounds perfect, anyway I'm going to use "slicedtoad" suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently, it's in the sense of "to have a way with things" http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+way+with

Comment: @Kris So, `I have an easy [action]` makes sense to you?

Comment: @slicedtoad Please see my previous comment.

Comment: @Kris `Has a way with/of comprehending` works fine, but it isn't the same as `Has an easy comprehension of`. Replace `comprehension` with `building` (action). `I have an easy building` is wrong. Instead it would be `I have an easy time building`. Not the best example though.

Comment: Fvil: That's a mouth full!  Just say, "He's a quick learner."  Avoid 'wordy' language.

Answer (score 4):

It is not wrong, but it is unidiomatic.

When *easy* is applied to a task, it means "not causing difficulty".  "An easy climb", "an easy class", "easy as fishing".  Effectively, it means "done with ease".

When *easy* is applied to a human attribute, it usually means "unforced, natural".  "An easy smile", "an easy laugh".  It means "done *at* ease".

If you were to say someone had "an easy erudition", it would not mean he acquired the erudition easily, but that he displays it without the display seeming mannered or overbearing.

If you were to say someone had an "easy comprehension", my immediate interpretation would be that he comprehended the subject while seeming relaxed and unhurried.  Since that does not make much sense, I would eventually realize you meant that he had a "ready comprehension" of the subject matter, and that comprehending it was easy.

Answer (score 1):

> He has an easy comprehension of

`Easy comprehension` is OK is some contexts:

- Use a dictionary for the easy comprehension of the text.

But I can't think of way you could *have an easy comprehension*.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comprehension)

> COMPREHENSION
>
> a. the act or action of grasping with the intellect: [understanding](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/understanding)
>
> b. knowledge gained by [comprehending](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comprehending)
>
> c. the capacity for understanding fully <mysteries that are beyond
>   our comprehension>

The word `have` makes `comprehension` not *(a)*, an act or action, since you cannot have an action.

If it's *(b)*, knowledge gained, we have `he has an easy knowledge gained`, then `easy` is describing the knowledge and not the ability to gain it. This is unlikely to be the intended meaning. Instead you would need to change it to `he has an easy time gaining knowledge`

If it's *(c)*, the capacity for understanding fully, we have `he has an easy capacity for`. This is the closest meaning, but the word `easy` is a strange way to describe `capacity`. Instead, you would use `he has an excellent capacity for understanding x`.

Two good alternatives, depending on exactly what you want to say:

`He has an easy time comprehending theory and methodologies`

`He has an excellent comprehension of theory and methodologies`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 'has an easy understanding/comprehension of X' means 'has no trouble at all understanding X'. It means understanding comes naturally.

An example is given in Steve Weinburg's [A Journal of Humanity ...](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qCpBXQVX4LMC&pg=PA167&lpg=PA167&dq=%22has+an+easy+understanding%22&source=bl&ots=-OlDiHoaj0&sig=6ovb77U4R2YSwoSf01fOFKOlXJM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UubUVMPJE8j1UJuAgpAD&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22has%20an%20easy%20understanding%22&f=false)

> Atwater "is a sensible man, has an easy understanding of students and
>   what drives them ..."

[AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/easy)'s first definition for **easy** covers this sense [bolding mine]

easy  adj. ...

1.
a. Capable of being accomplished or **acquired** with ease; posing no difficulty:

**but** that doesn't mean that other collocations necessarily exist or have the same sense of 'easy' (*/?an easy wisdom; an easy life; an easy mark).

Comment: Can you actually use it the same way as `understanding`? `has an easy understanding of` is fairly common, but as you mention, that structure of `an easy x` isn't a general rule.  I can only find uses of `an easy comprehension` in book titles and the like, where it's promising an easy comprehension. `I have an easy comprehension` just sounds wrong.

Comment: Good point. There _are_ surprisingly few Google hits for "have an easy comprehension of", but 'comprehension' and 'understanding' are such close synonyms here that I don't think many people happy with one would be unhappy with the other. Other examples include 'has an easy intelligence / wisdom'. Again, they're rare, but the 'this character trait comes naturally' sense of 'easy' isn't very common overall.